# First Order Logic problem with Compactness theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let Γ a set of sentences such that every interpretation makes true at least one sentence of Γ. Show that there is a finite set of sentences Γ such that the disjunction of its elements is going to be a valid formula.

Tip: construct Γ from one unsatisfiable set and apply Compactness theorem.

Comment: Can you guide me to answer it ?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Delta$ be the set of negations of sentences of $\Gamma$. We show that  some conjunction of sentences of $\Delta$ is inconsistent.

For suppose to the contrary that every finite subset of $\Delta$ is consistent. Then by Compactness there is a model of $\Delta$, that is, a structure $M$ in which all the sentences of $\Delta$ are true. Thus *all* sentences of $\Gamma$ are false in $M$. This contradicts the given fact that in every interpretation at least one sentence of $\Gamma$ is true.

So some finite subset of $\Delta$ is inconsistent. Suppose that this subset consists of the sentences $\lnot\phi_i$, $i=1$ to $n$. Then the disjunction of the $\phi_i$ is valid.

Comment: Wooow, thanks for you help, I see it now.

Comment: You are welcome. It was one one step away from Compactness.